# jQuery-style hover CSS styling in React.js app

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

I have a React.js app that adds items to a list. In my index.html file, I am using jQuery to facilitate hovering over certain elements leading to changing the style on other elements. However, after new items are added, jQuery seems not to recognize them.

```
$(".list-item").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #000");
    $("."+this.childNodes[0].classList[0]+" .item").css("display", "block");
    $("h2."+this.childNodes[0].classList[0]).css({"color":"#555"});
}, function(){
     ...
})
```

This works for list items that are present when the app is loaded, but not for elements added later by the user. Is there a way to make jQuery recognize the new elements, or is there a better method using only CSS or React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:hover` CSS pseudo class. Don't do it with jQuery.

```
.list-item:hover
    border: 1px solid #000
    ...

    h2
    .other-class
    .etc
```